# How to average coherences estimated using Welch's method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to estimate the average coherence of discontinuous snippets of a signal in MATLAB. For Welch's spectrum estimates, the following works:

```
w = blackmanharris(50);  % window
n = numel(w);            % fft length
o = 0;                   % overlap

x = rand(200,1); x1 = x(1:100); x2 = x(101:200);

s  = pwelch(x,  w, o, n);
s1 = pwelch(x1, w, o, n);
s2 = pwelch(x2, w, o, n);
sa = (s1+s2)/2;

max(abs(s-sa))  % almost zero
```

However, when estimating coherences using Welch's method, the arithmetic mean yields an incorrect result:

```
y = rand(200,1); y1 = y(1:100); y2 = y(101:200);

c  = mscohere(x,  y,  w, o, n);
c1 = mscohere(x1, y1, w, o, n);
c2 = mscohere(x2, y2, w, o, n);
ca = (c1+c2)/2;

max(abs(c-ca))  % very different from zero
```

How can I average two coherence estimates correctly?

Comment: Questions like this are better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: All right: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17711/